# PDF file on IIS site is not accessible when opened from a browser

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I am creating a PDF file with IIS (with some code) and save it to a folder which has IIS anonymous authentication enabled.

When I try to open it through its URL, IIS gives me a 401 "Unauthorized" error. When I manually copy+paste a file to the same folder, it opens fine.

When looking at the ACL of the PDF, 3 users have "Access deny". When I delete those, the PDF opens just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the upload tmp directory to somewhere with IIS_IUSRS permissions as needed.

Uploaded files inherit the permissions of this **temporary directory**, as they are moved (taking their permission with them) when the upload is finished.

Comment: The folder where I am uploading the files has IIS_IUSRS permissions as needed. The problem is file is not inheriting it by its own and have to manually give the permission.

Comment: IIS does *never* upload files directly to your target folder, but to a temp folder instad. The file is moved afterwards, so it takes it's permission from the temp-folder with it. IIS's Temp folder (usually) has no ACL for IIS_IUSER.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, you mean to say if I save a file with some code to a folder say quote file in a website on IIS having path like this:  www.cdn.abc.com/quotefile where quotefile folder has IIS_IUSRS permissions, it will 1st save save it to some temp folder and then cipy to quote file? If thats true then how can I save that temp folder path in IIS, I don't know what that path is and how can we change it. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: I am able to fix the issue after giving the permission to temp folder where file was being saved first.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the pdf file's permissions to enable anonymous users to read it. follow the steps below:

To adjust the file's permissions, open the properties dialogue for the PDF file, select the security tab, click the edit button, add the "IIS_IUSRS" group to the list of users, and grant it the "Read & Execute" permission. Then, click the OK button to save your changes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution and it works if I go to each file and add the IIS_IUSRS. I am creating files in program code automatically and newly created files are giving same Unauthorized error. I tried adding IIS_IUSRS to folder which contain files but that also not helping out.